# How to create byte array with your own bytes?

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

I have to create my own byte array e.g:

```
byte[] connect = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x21, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, 0x07 };
```

This byte array works fine, but I need to change some hex code. I tried to do a lot of changes but
no one work.

```
Int32 hex = 0xA1; 

byte[] connect = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x21, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, hex};


string hex = "0xA1"; 

byte[] connect = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x21, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, hex};


byte[] array = new byte[1];
array[0] = 0xA1;

byte[] connect = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x21, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, array[0]};
```

I don't know what type of variable I must have to use to replace automatic the array values.

Comment: It's a byte array. So each element of that array is a ....?

Comment: And question is down-voted because ... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast your int to byte:

```
Int32 hex = 0xA1; 
byte[] connect = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x21, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, (byte)hex};
```

Or define it as byte to begin with:

```
byte hex = 0xA1; 
byte[] connect = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x21, 0x60, 0x1F, 0xA1, hex};
```

String to byte conversion:

```
static byte hexstr2byte(string s)
{
    if (!s.StartsWith("0x") || s.Length != 4)
        throw new FormatException();
    return byte.Parse(s.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}
```

As you can see, .NET formatting supports hexa digits, but not the "0x" prefix. It would be easier to omit that part altogether, but your question isn't exactly clear about that.

Comment: Thanks ! Your examples works fine. But I receive the value in String and when I try to Convert.ToInt32(hex) I got an exception: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: You didn't exactly say in your question that you want to convert from string... I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it like "byte hex = 0xA1" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

On a WinCE5 system I had to pass a char-string from a C# app to a c-dll. To form up the char string in the c# code I had to cast to byte (like @fejesjoco suggested). So to form the string test_ I had           `byte[] name_comms_layer = new byte[] {(byte)0x74,(byte) 0x65,(byte)0x73,(byte)0x74,(byte)0x5f,(byte) 0x00} //test_`
Painful but it did work.